# How to style caption of vaadin textarea component

Tags: vaadin

I'm wondering how to style the caption of a vaadin textarea/textfield component?

I tried something like

```
.v-textarea-mystyle .v-captiontext {
   font-size: 24px;
   font-weidht: bold;
}
```

but that doesn't seem to work! Any suggestions?

Regards,
Gerard

Comment: did you add your style with textfield.addStyleName("v-textarea-mystyle") ?

Comment: No, I added textarea.addStyleName("mystyle")!

Comment: Just for completeness: You've got a typo in weidht => weight

Answer (score 0):

(at least for Vaadin 7.2 and a `VerticalLayout`) the caption is not within the `.v-texarea` element.

```
.v-caption-mystyle .v-captiontext {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weidht: bold;
}
```

and you have to `addStyleName('mystyle')` on each such textarea.

your alternative is to write some smart CSS, that says "the .v-caption .vcaptiontext before the textarea"

Comment: i would not be surprised, if this is actually a bug

Comment: Does this mean the caption cannot be styled seperately?

Comment: of course it can.  ``textarea.addStyleName('mystyle')`` -- but it has to be set on "all" textareas or you have to write some smart CSS, that does it by relation to the textarea.